# Is it possible to update Android Manifest programmatically at runtime?

Tags: android, android-manifest

#### What I want to achieve:

> I am creating an application which changes the app icon and app name programmatically.

#### What I have achieved:

> I've already achieved this because there are only 5 names and icons by declaring activity-alias in android manifest.

#### Problem I'm facing:

> If you have only 5 names then it's easy to declare it in manifest. But what if you don't know the no. of names and you have to update the manifest programmatically.

Below is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drawerstack">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:name=".MainActivity-Red"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_1"
            android:name=".MainActivity-Pink"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_2"
            android:name=".MainActivity-Blue"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name4"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_3"
            android:name=".MainActivity-Grey"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In **MainActivity.java**

```
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getTag().equals(0)) {
                changeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Red");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Pink");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Blue");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Grey");
            } else if (view.getTag().equals(1)) {
                changeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Pink");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Blue");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Grey");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Red");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity");
            } else if (view.getTag().equals(2)) {
                changeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Blue");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Pink");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Grey");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Red");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity");
            } else if (view.getTag().equals(3)) {
                changeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Grey");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Pink");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Red");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity-Blue");
                removeIcon("com.drawerstack.MainActivity");
            }
        }
    });


private void changeIcon(final String pkgName) {

    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Date now = new Date();
            if(now.after(afterDate)){
                timer.cancel();
                Common.dismissProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000);

    Common.loadProgressDialog(MainActivity.this,false);
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName("com.drawerstack", pkgName),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}


private void removeIcon(String removePkg) {
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.drawerstack", removePkg),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: Assuming your question is the one in title `Is it possible to update Android Manifest programmatically?` the answer is **no**, it is not possible to do that programmatically.

Comment: @azizbekian Not even a single way to achieve that??

Comment: You can enable/disable components that are declared in your manifest, but you cannot add or remove something from there, because, as the name says, it's a manifest file, which system "reads" when it installs your app. So you are declaring your app's interface in that manifest, later on you cannot change that (unless you reinstall the app with another manifest).

Comment: I'll post those comments as an answer.

Comment: "unless you reinstall the app with another manifest" is it really possible??

Comment: If you change your manifest and install the new `apk`, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your question is the one in title:

> Is it possible to update Android Manifest programmatically?

The answer is **no**, it is not possible to do that programmatically.

You can enable/disable components that are declared in your manifest, but you cannot add or remove something from there, because, as the name says, it's a manifest file, which system "reads" when it installs your app. So you are declaring your app's interface in that manifest, later on you cannot change that, unless you reinstall the app with another manifest.

Assume system provided you ability to do that. Then you'd add some permission to your manifest dynamically, whereas user hasn't approved that while he was downloading your app from Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

**You can change the manifest meta value for Admob or any string by using this code:**

```
package com.asdf.loanapp;

import android.os.Build;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ModifyManifest {

static String readFileString;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Specify the path to the         
 AndroidManifest.xml file
    String manifestFilePath =     "/path/to/AndroidManifest.xml";

    // Specify the name of the metadata element     you want to modify
    String metadataName = "your_metadata_name";

    // Specify the new metadata value
    String newMetadataValue =     "place_your_admob_string_here";

        try {
        // Read the contents of the     AndroidManifest.xml file
            String manifestContent =     readFile(manifestFilePath);

            // Modify the metadata value
            manifestContent =     modifyMetadata(manifestContent, metadataName,     newMetadataValue);

            // Save the modified content back     to the file
            saveFile(manifestContent, manifestFilePath);

            System.out.println("Metadata in     AndroidManifest.xml modified successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    // Read the contents of a file

    private static String readFile(String     filePath) throws IOException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            readFileString = new     String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
        }
        return readFileString;
    }

    // Modify the metadata value in the     AndroidManifest.xml
    private static String modifyMetadata(String     manifestContent, String metadataName, String newMetadataValue) {
        // Find and replace the metadata value
        String oldMetadataTag = "<meta-data     android:name=\"" + metadataName + "\"";
        int startIndex =     manifestContent.indexOf(oldMetadataTag);
        if (startIndex != -1) {
            int endIndex =     manifestContent.indexOf(">", startIndex);
            if (endIndex != -1) {
                // Extract the existing value
                String existingMetadataTag =     manifestContent.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                String existingValue =     extractMetadataValue(existingMetadataTag);
               

                // Create the new metadata tag with the modified value
                String newMetadataTag = "<meta-data android:name=\"" + metadataName + "\"     android:value=\"" + newMetadataValue + "\" />";

                // Replace the old metadata tag     with the new one
                manifestContent =     manifestContent.replace(existingMetadataTag,     newMetadataTag);
            }
        }
        return manifestContent;
    }

    // Extract the value attribute from a     metadata tag
        private static String     extractMetadataValue(String metadataTag) {
        Pattern pattern =     Pattern.compile("android:value=\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher matcher =     pattern.matcher(metadataTag);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Save modified content back to the file
    private static void saveFile(String     content, String filePath) throws IOException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=     Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath),     content.getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```