# How to open specific app's specific activity clicking on an external link?

Tags: android, android-activity, uri

I am developing an android app, in which user must need to login first to use it's features. So as usual user must need to login using provided user credential.

But I don't want user always enter username and password again and again, so that I am just sharing a URL with user and if user click on shared link from anywhere in phone (via mail, or WhatsApp, or Facebook, etc.) phone must prompt to choose my app and app should automatically extract the URL and directly redirect the app to my Home Screen by hitting the login api if username and password are correct.

The shared url will be look like this - http://www.myurl.com/sso?username=Scb56745&password=!l0Aeu0yQazxssx

For now I have managed to prompt the dialog using this code in my AndroidManifest file -

```
 <activity
         android:name="com.my.par.activities.UserActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.myurl.com"
                        android:path="/sso"
                        android:scheme="http" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.yoururl.com"
                        android:path="/sso1"
                        android:scheme="https" />
         </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I am getting this clicked URL link in my UserAcitivity's on getIntent() method, like this -

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String path = uri.getPath();
```

- So my real question is how to extract the username and password separately and so that I can call my login api by sending this username and password from this url (for ex. http://www.myurl.com/sso?username=Scb56745&password=!l0Aeu0yQazxssx). - **Done**
- And how can I put a dynamic URL or host name, path and scheme in AndroidMenifest file? - **Done**
- How can we force our app to always directly open the app,(don't need to show the chooser dialog) because no use of it even user click on browser nothing gonna happen.

Happy coding :-)

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic URL?

Comment: What if I have a choice of debug and release mode and having 2 endpoints for particular flavor than?? for ex. if I have 2 type URL then ?https://www.myurl2ndurl.com/sso?username=Scb56745&password=!l0Aeu0yQazxssx

Comment: I mean what if my scheme changed from http to https then?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karzel is also right but it's written in `Kotlin`, I believe you are expecting the solution for `Java` I'll answer the same in `Java`

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String strUsername = "", strPassword = "";
if (uri != null) {
   strUsername = uri.getQueryParameter("username");
   strPassword = uri.getQueryParameter("password");
}
else {
   // Your app will pop up even if http://www.myurl.com/sso is clicked, so better to handle null uri
}
```

To answer your next part about dynamic URL, you can have multiple `intent-filters` for that purpose

```
<activity
         android:name="com.my.par.activities.UserActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.myurl.com"
                        android:path="/sso"
                        android:scheme="http" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.myurl.com"
                        android:path="/sso"
                        android:scheme="https" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.myurl.com"
                        android:path="/debug"
                        android:scheme="http" />
         </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

and so on.

To open your app directly by clicking the link and not show a chooser dialog you'll have to use a custom URI, for example:

```
syn3sthete://myurl.com/sso?username=Scb56745&password=!l0Aeu0yQazxssx
```

You can change `syn3sthete` to any custom value you want.
Don't forget to add an `intent-filter` for your custom URI.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="myurl.com"
                        android:path="/sso"
                        android:scheme="syn3sthete" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think this is better, @syn3shtete can we force that whenever user click on link directly open the app only, there should not be any chooser dialog, because if user even try to click on browser then nothing gonna happen, so I am thinking it will be good we open the app directly... any idea?

Comment: @BajrangHudda That also can be done check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using code like this :

```
fun getUsernameFromUrl(url: String): String? {
    return Uri.parse(url).getQueryParameter("username")
}
fun getPasswordFromUrl(url: String): String? {
    return Uri.parse(url).getQueryParameter("password")
}
```

And call it

```
val username = getUsernameFromUrl(path)
```

etc.

**UPDATE:**

The only "dynamic" way of adding URL I know is using something like this :
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables
you can change this URL depending on your Build Variant.

As is said here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43339476/8713068
you cannot update Android Manifest directly from code